# MySQL service doesn't start up on Ubuntu 16.04 pam_unix problem

Tags: server, mysql

MySQL Community Server 5.7 (installed via apt) runs on a hosted virtual server, the service only starts up again successfully when I restart the server. But even then the mysql service doesn't start up occasionally.

journalct -xe shows:

```
Nov 16 15:10:28 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Nov 16 15:10:28 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 16 15:10:45 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal vsftpd[4760]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 16 15:10:45 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal vsftpd[4760]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=f
Nov 16 15:10:58 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Nov 16 15:10:58 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 16 15:10:58 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 15:10:58 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 16 15:10:58 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 16 15:10:58 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Nov 16 15:10:58 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysql.service: 
Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

So it says:

```
[...] vsftpd[4760]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): check pass; user unknown
[...] vsftpd[4760]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=f
```

I have no idea what this message points to.

Do I have to edit the service or the init.d script? Does anyone with more linux knowledge know how to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "vsftpd" ?

Maybe if you remove it you won't have the issue again

```
sudo apt-get remove vsftpd
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I removed vsftpd. This now leads to  pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=61.XXX.172.XXX  user=root
; sshd[8767]: Failed password for root from 61.XXX.172.XXX port 58950 ssh2

Answer (score 0):

If there is no sock file then you need to create mysqld.sock file and assign ownership of mysql by this command:

```
##touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

## chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
## chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

and go to your my.cnf file and comment out this line:

```
#log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log   ----- like this..
```